# Manipulating a given DataFrame in order to recreate it in a different structure, Pandas Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization

[Left DataFrame is the given one, and i want to recreate it to the right DataFrame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkh75.png)

Hi,
So suppose i have a given DataFrame (the left one), and i want to create a new dataframe (the right one).
I created the new DataFrame with the indexes and columns of the right one, and now i want to "fill" the cells.
Any ideas how can i do it simplest, with priority of vectorize way?
Thank you in advance!

I did it with loops not "classic" way. I would like to write it with apply method or another smart solution.

edit:
this is an approcah that i tried:

This is the original DataFrame with filled data [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP8zm.png)

This is the DataFrame i want to reach [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38xtf.png)

This is a step i tried to do in order to reach the solution[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Bc5.png)

the output should be (also in context for Scot's answer):
in [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi8gA.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I would like to write it with apply method or another smart solution."  - then please do, and share with us if you hit an error / issue we can help you with :)

Comment: I think you need to use the `pivot` function.

Comment: i will attach an approach i tried. thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am little confused by your question, but I will attempt an answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(1, 76).reshape(-1,5, order='F'), 
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3,4,5],[*'XYZ']]), 
                  columns='Shirt Bottomware Shoes Sunglasses Earrings'.split())    
df = df.rename_axis(['Number', 'Variable'])
df
```

Input Dataframe:

```
                 Shirt  Bottomware  Shoes  Sunglasses  Earrings
Number Variable                                                
1      X             1          16     31          46        61
       Y             2          17     32          47        62
       Z             3          18     33          48        63
2      X             4          19     34          49        64
       Y             5          20     35          50        65
       Z             6          21     36          51        66
3      X             7          22     37          52        67
       Y             8          23     38          53        68
       Z             9          24     39          54        69
4      X            10          25     40          55        70
       Y            11          26     41          56        71
       Z            12          27     42          57        72
5      X            13          28     43          58        73
       Y            14          29     44          59        74
       Z            15          30     45          60        75
```

Reshape and filter:

```
df_out = df.unstack().stack(0, dropna=False).loc[[(1,'Shirt'),(3,'Shoes'),(5,'Earrings')]]    
df_out
```

Output dataframe:

```
Variable          X   Y   Z
Number                     
1      Shirt      1   2   3
3      Shoes     37  38  39
5      Earrings  73  74  75
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!
The output is not what i was looking for, i will try to be more clear.
I want each row to be the value of each variable within the same number.
so,
the output should be:
Variable          X   Y   Z
Number                     
1      Shirt      1   6   11
3      Shoes     31  36  41
5      Earrings  61  66  71

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so i tried to run it, your solution is actually right!
the output you posted here is incorrect, thank you very much! appreciated!